# how to identify where of a column is more rich in one values?

Tags: r

If i generate randomly a binary data frame like below

```
Mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 200*50, replace = TRUE),200,50)
```

If I have 200 rows for each column and I set a threshold like 50 up and 30 down. 
how can I check whether the 50 rows in top of each column contains more 1 values or the 30 rows down of each column or the middle ?

how can I then plot something to show graphically the results ?

By doing

```
f <- function(x, u = 200, d = 200){
  res <- list(NA)
  for(i in 1:ncol(x)){
    res[[i]] <- c(sum(x[1:u,i] == 1), sum(x[(u+1):(nrow(x)- d),i] == 1), sum(x[(nrow(x)-d+1):nrow(x),i] == 1))
  }
  res <- do.call(rbind, res)
  res
}
```

then calculate

```
res_value <- f(output)
```

the res_values can be found here 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a1f68b9798affe630e65

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(c(t(res_value)), rep(1:50, each = 3)), X3 = rep(1:3))

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(X2), y = X1, fill = as.factor(X3))) + geom_bar(position="fill", stat = "identity")
```

I got a warning like below

```
Warning message:
In cbind(c(t(res_value)), rep(1:50, each = 3)) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

and of course the plot is like below which is not good at all

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? First write a function to calculate the number of ones in each of the three groups using the thresholds (`u` and `d`) and then plot the result as filled barplot:

```
f <- function(x, u = 50, d = 30){
    res <- list(NA)
    for(i in 1:ncol(x)){
        res[[i]] <- c(sum(x[1:u,i] == 1), sum(x[(u+1):(nrow(x)- d),i] == 1), sum(x[(nrow(x)-d+1):nrow(x),i] == 1))
    }
    res <- do.call(rbind, res)
    res
}


res <- f(Mat)
df <- data.frame(cbind(c(t(res)), rep(1:50, each = 3)), X3 = rep(1:3))
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(X2), y = X1, fill = as.factor(X3))) + geom_bar(position="fill", stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Group 1 is the upper group, 2 the middle and 3 the bottom group. If you want the exact numers to be plotted instead of normalized values you can set `position = stack`

Comment: thanks for your comment, I liked it and I am checking whether it gives me the answer

Comment: I found your solution the best so far because this is what I am looking for. However, i am wondering what are rep(1:50, each = 3)), X3 = rep(1:3)) in your command ?

Comment: This is a trick for data restructuring to bring it in the form which can be used for `ggplot`

Comment: when I did as you said, I got warning and a strange output plot. I show the plot above, please look at it and let me know where I should amend

Comment: somehting I am definitely sure is that I have 55 of 1 values in each column , I will post the res_value in the main question too

Comment: Your `u` and `d` values don't make sense, do they?

Comment: on my real data set, they do make sense, I have over 20000 rows, so they make sense. now I posted the res_values in the main question. the first column is the row.names(ignore it) we only have 3 columns called V1, V2 and V3

Comment: But they differ from the matrix you supplied in the question. Do you only want to include the second and fourth columns?

Comment: the data is different for sure! I want exactly plot what you plotted for the previous data, blow, green and red for up/middle and bottom .

Comment: For the first and third columns that deosn't make sense, because there are no 1's in those columns

Comment: do you know a better way to show such things? however, I changed the res_value, now there are more values in 1 and 3

Comment: So what is your goal now? Do you still want to check the number of 1's in the upper, in the middle and in the lower parts?

Comment: yes, I just changed the threshold from 200 to 2000 so that I can have more data which is meaningful for the plot

Comment: Please first think thorough what you want, because this doens't make sense

Comment: I know what I want, I just want to plot the same as your plot on the res_value I gave above , that is all what I want

Answer (score 0):

This is how to view the matrix...

```
image(Mat)
```

[image: the output]

Comment: thanks but this is not the solution I am looking for! as I wrote , I want to put a threshold and find values then plot the results not just use image , Can you tell me about the first column based on your plot? it is not possible , so thanks for your help but this is definitely not the answer !

Answer (score 0):

```
library(reshape2)
library(gplots)
library(ggplot2)

Mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 200*50, replace = TRUE), 200, 50)

low_cut  <- 50
high_cut <- 30

lows   <- apply(Mat, 2, function(x) sum(x[1:low_cut]))
highs  <- apply(Mat, 2, function(x) sum(x[(length(x)-high_cut):length(x)]))
totals <- colSums(Mat)
mids   <- totals - lows - highs

results <- data.frame(id    = 1:NCOL(Mat),
                      lows  = lows,
                      mids  = mids,
                      highs = highs)

excludeVars <- names(results) %in% c('id')

image(as.matrix(results[!excludeVars]))
heatmap.2(as.matrix(results[!excludeVars]),
          trace = "none")

melted_results <- melt(results, id.vars = "id")
ggplot(melted_results, aes(x=variable, y=id)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value))
```

[image: Plot1]
[image: Plot2]
[image: Plot3]

Comment: thanks for your comment! although it is close but not the exact answer. If you read my question carefully, I want to check for each column separately while you basically calculate it for entire data frame sum(Mat[1:low_cut,]).

Comment: Just realized that, will adjust shortly

Comment: I read your question carefully and can't make any sense of it.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns thanks for your comment, I liked it and I am checking whether it gives me the answer

Comment: @JasonAizkalns thank again for your answer but i did not accept your answer because I want to plot the up and bottom and mid where we take care of 1 values and not zeros , in your function you just calculate whatever is there, so it is not what I really wanted

Comment: @Nemo Not sure I (and others) fully understand. Perhaps strip your question down to a smaller matrix (10 by 10) and hone in on your desired output?  What does success look like?  What are the expected results?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns the answer given by RStudent is very close ! expected results can be seen in his file named "res" . however, I already appreciated for all the effort you put on this question :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 200*50, replace = TRUE),200,50)

high_t<-70
bottom_t<-70

sums <- rbind(colSums(Mat[1:high_t,]),colSums(Mat[(high_t+1):(nrow(Mat)-bottom_t),]),colSums(Mat[(nrow(Mat)-bottom_t+1):nrow(Mat),]))
res <- apply(sums,2,which.max)
```

For each interval, use `colSums` to sum the columns, then `rbind` the results and use `which.max` to find which interval has the most 1s, 1 for top, 2 for middle and 3 for bottom.

I changed your thresholds because the middle always wins if you choose 50 and 30 (the middle then has 120 rows)

Comment: thanks for your comment, I liked it and I am checking whether it gives me the answer

Comment: i did not accept your answer because I want to plot the up and bottom and mid where we take care of 1 values and not zeros , in your function you just calculate whatever is there, so it is not what I really wanted